# Blur controls beneath another control

Tags: .net, wpf, effects

If I have layers of controls such as:

```
Window
 - Grid1 (containing various UI elements)
  - GridBlurOverlay (does nothing except blur Grid1)
 - Grid2 (containing a single UI element (e.g. a "please wait" control)
```

How can I apply a blue effect to grid1 and it's contents, without actually setting it's `Effect` property? I had hoped that if I created an overlay (as in the example) that this would work, but in fact the blur effect only affects the control and it's children, not it's parent. I.e. it's not like placing frosted glass over Grid1, which is the effect I was after.

I'm guessing I need to do something messy like set the background of GridBlurOverlay to a VisualBrush based on Grid1, but I'm wondering exactly what the approach might be, and if there's something more elegant (and with better performance)?

Comment: Why wouldn't you want to set the `Effect` property?

Answer (score 0):

If GridBlurOverlay is a noisy & opaque, wouldn't playing with it's opacity give you the desired effect?

Answer (score 0):

is this what you want?

**EDIT (Update)**

```
<Grid HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"
      VerticalAlignment="Stretch">

  <Grid>
    <!-- you can activate this if you want this effect -->
    <Grid.Background>
      <SolidColorBrush Color="Gray" Opacity="0.6"/>
    </Grid.Background>
    <Grid.Effect>
      <BlurEffect Radius="5"/>
    </Grid.Effect>

    <TextBlock VerticalAlignment="Top"
               Text="Some Controls"
               FontSize="60" />
  </Grid>

  <Border Background="Gray" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center">
    <TextBlock Text="Please Wait"
               FontSize="60" />
  </Border>
</Grid>
```

Comment: I think "blue effect" in the original post was supposed to read "blur effect."

Comment: This is precisely what the poster says he does *not* want to do -- apply the blur effect directly to the `Grid` that contains the other controls (though I still wonder why that is the requirement).